# HDF5 headers missing in installation of netCDF4 module for Python

Tags: python, hdf5, netcdf

I have attempted to install the netCDF4 module several times now and I keep getting the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\netCDF4\setup.py", line 219, in <module>

    raise ValueError('did not find HDF5 headers')

ValueError: did not find HDF5 headers
```

I tried using the official HDF installer from their website and I am still getting the same error (though during the installation the setup warned me that the PATH is too long and so it will not alter it.

Where do these header files need to be? At the moment I (think) have them in

```
C:\Program Files\HDF_Group\HDF5
```

I am not really familiar with what I need to do? If it matters I have also installed the h5py module.

(Windows 8.1)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a file `setup.cfg` in the base of source tree (you can base it on the `setup.cfg.template` that should be there). Specifically, you'll want to set the value of `HDF5_dir` within the file.

Comment: I did that with the `setup.py` file and it got past the HDF5 error, but then it said it couldn't find the netCDF4 headers. I changed the `netcdf4_dir` variable to where the headers are but I don't think it recognised them due to a version mismatch (I think).

Comment: Double check the case of the variable you used for netcdf4: `netCDF4_dir` is the spelling that's in `setup.cfg.template`. Also, the output of `setup.py` should list the locations being checked.

Comment: Ok I will do that. I have a feeling I don't actually have these netCDF4 headers - do you know where I can get them from? I tried the official website but I wasn't sure what I was doing to be fair.

Comment: The latest version is here: https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf-c/releases/tag/v4.3.3.1