# Python netCDF4 install error

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04, netcdf4

I'm trying to install netCDF4 package for python 2.7 on Ubuntu 14.04 with

```
sudo pip install --user netCDF4
```

The installation crashes with the following error:

```
error: unknown file type '.pyx' (from 'netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx')
```

The only hint I found from other threads was that this has something to do with pyrex/Cython. Any idea what I can do to fix this?

Here's the entire output from the installation:

```
haaviston@tuomi13kl:~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources$ pip install --user netCDF4
Downloading/unpacking netCDF4
  Downloading netCDF4-1.3.0.tar.gz (542kB): 542kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_haaviston/netCDF4/setup.py) egg_info for package netCDF4
    Package hdf5 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `hdf5.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'hdf5' found
    using nc-config ...

        HDF5_DIR environment variable not set, checking some standard locations ..
    checking /home/haaviston ...
    checking /usr/local ...
    checking /sw ...
    checking /opt ...
    checking /opt/local ...
    checking /usr ...
    HDF5 library version: 1.8.11 found in /usr
    using netcdf library version 4.1.3
    using Cython to compile netCDF4.pyx...
    netcdf lib does not have group rename capability
    netcdf lib has nc_inq_path function
    netcdf lib does not have nc_inq_format_extended function
    netcdf lib does not have nc_open_mem function
    netcdf lib does not have cdf-5 format capability

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy>=1.7 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from netCDF4)
Installing collected packages: netCDF4
  Running setup.py install for netCDF4
    Package hdf5 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `hdf5.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'hdf5' found
    using nc-config ...

        HDF5_DIR environment variable not set, checking some standard locations ..
    checking /home/haaviston ...
    checking /usr/local ...
    checking /sw ...
    checking /opt ...
    checking /opt/local ...
    checking /usr ...
    HDF5 library version: 1.8.11 found in /usr
    using netcdf library version 4.1.3
    using Cython to compile netCDF4.pyx...
    netcdf lib does not have group rename capability
    netcdf lib has nc_inq_path function
    netcdf lib does not have nc_inq_format_extended function
    netcdf lib does not have nc_open_mem function
    netcdf lib does not have cdf-5 format capability
    building 'netCDF4._netCDF4' extension
    error: unknown file type '.pyx' (from 'netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx')
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_haaviston/netCDF4/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-5Mjz_n-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user:
    Package hdf5 was not found in the pkg-config search path.

Perhaps you should add the directory containing `hdf5.pc'

to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable

No package 'hdf5' found

reading from setup.cfg...

using nc-config ...



    HDF5_DIR environment variable not set, checking some standard locations ..

checking /home/haaviston ...

checking /usr/local ...

checking /sw ...

checking /opt ...

checking /opt/local ...

checking /usr ...

HDF5 library version: 1.8.11 found in /usr

using netcdf library version 4.1.3

using Cython to compile netCDF4.pyx...

netcdf lib does not have group rename capability

netcdf lib has nc_inq_path function

netcdf lib does not have nc_inq_format_extended function

netcdf lib does not have nc_open_mem function

netcdf lib does not have cdf-5 format capability

running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/netcdftime

copying netcdftime/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/netcdftime

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/netCDF4

copying netCDF4/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/netCDF4

copying netCDF4/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/netCDF4

running build_ext

building 'netCDF4._netCDF4' extension

error: unknown file type '.pyx' (from 'netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx')

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_haaviston/netCDF4/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-5Mjz_n-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_haaviston/netCDF4
Storing debug log for failure in /home/haaviston/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: See if installing the `cython` package helps; but it may be something bad in the netCDF4 setup itself (if only that it should have checked for Cython itself, and exit with a proper error message if that doesn't exist).

Comment: Cython is already installed :/

Comment: Then either the build tools can't find Cython, or netCDF4's installation is set up incorrectly. Can you run the installation again, with a `-v` or even `-vv` (verbose) option? That may give a lot of info; just find the relevant stuff from where it's building `netCDF4._netCDF4`. Seeing the actual builder/compiler commands may be helpful.

Comment: pip install --user -verbose didn't output anything about netCDF4._netCDF4 that wasn't in the output I posted :( There was a warning: `writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/netCDF4.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found`

Could this have something to do with the hdf5 package, even though the setup seems to get around not finding it at first?

Comment: Have you tried installing netcdf4-python using conda? It's been the best for me. https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/netcdf4

Comment: I guess I'll go with that or upgrade to Ubuntu 16 and see if the problem goes away with a clean os

Comment: You are missing HDF5 installation: "Perhaps you should add the directory containing `hdf5.pc". Some thing like "sudo apt-get install libhdf5-serial-dev netcdf-bin libnetcdf-dev". See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36164410/for-python-install-hdf5-netcdf4

Comment: I tried all that without success. Managed now to install an older version with `pip install --user netCDF4==1.2.2`